# How do I configure url pages for 404 errors in Kentico?

Tags: kentico

In my kentico app I have a lot of server side requests with 404 errors and all with a generic url like /CMSPages/PortalTemplate.aspx. I would like to get the correct urls that originated in the error.

Comment: Do I get it right that the "Event Url" field in the Event Log is empty?

Comment: Reviewing IIS logs might be the easiest answer.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I am having the same issue, the /CMSPages/PortalTemplate.aspx throws 404 errors but the requests are fulfilled and I can't see where this page is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the event log does not provide enough details about the original URL you can always hook to the `PageNotFound` global event and explore (debug) the `URLRewritingEventArgs`. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Reference+-+Global+system+events#Reference-Globalsystemevents-URLRewritingEvents).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually Im using kentico with Azure, and I would like to log the correct 404 urls in Application Insights Azure. Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: And have you actually tried it? Is the `PortalTemplate.aspx` what's being logged by Application Insights? Can you perhaps share some more details/screenshots?
+ I'd recommend reading [this nice article](https://www.mcbeev.com/Blog/April-2016/Application-Insights-for-Kentico) by Brian McKeiver on using Application Insights with Kentico.

Comment: @rocky I am having a similar issue, been investigating for 2 weeks now, it looks like most request go via  /CMSPages/PortalTemplate.aspx on Kentico, then the 404 errors are thrown, how ever the site still usable. I only see the errors on iis logs